# Unable to set Parse installation to two channels for push notification

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to have a part of my Parse cloud code set the installation channel for push notification purposes. I want it to set the installation to two channels like so:

```
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
installationQuery.equalTo('userId', user);

installationQuery.first().then(function(result) {
   result.set('channels', [user, "highPush"]);
   result.save();
});
```

What I'm doing here is finding the installation associated with a particular `userId`, then setting that `installation` object's 'channels' property to both the username ( the `user` variable) string, and the string "highPush".

The problem is that running this code only seems to set it to "highPush", not both. When I try using an explicit `user` string like below, it successfully sets it to both, but not when I use the `user` variable which contains that same userId string. What could be causing this?

```
result.set('channels', ["EG7Mf6mDkT", "highPush"]);
```

Logging the `user` variable like below succesfully prints, so I know it exists.

```
console.log('set it to high push, and the userId is' + user);
```

Comment: Is user a Parse.User object?...

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical that `user` is really a string here.  Are you sure that `user` isn't a `Parse.User`?

If it is indeed a `Parse.User` object, get at the objectId with:

```
result.set('channels', [user.id, "highPush"]);
```